# Calculation of gradient and hessian

Tags: gradient-descent

Let the function on $E = R ^ 2$ by $j (x, y) = x^2-xy+y^2+3x-2y+1$. Calculate the associated gradient and hessian. Deduce the value of a local minimal point is this a strict minimum.
To answer this simplistic example, i begin by calculating the derivatives.

**Gradient:** 
 $D'<f(x, y)/x> = 2x-y+3 $

$D'<f(x, y)/y> = 2y-x-2 $

Hessian:

$D''<f(x, y)/x^2> = 2 $

$D''<f(y)/y^2>= 2 $

And the value of a local minimal is a = (1,1) ?

Comment: Where comes from the point $a=(1,1)$? The minimum ( if it exists) is a point where the gradient is null.

Comment: You can calculate the value of a local minimum point and what is a strict minimumn thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Let: $$J(x,y) = x^2-xy+y^2+3x-2y+1$$
Then:
$$\partial_x J = 2x-y+3 \;\;\;\;\&\;\;\;\;\partial_yJ=-x+2y-2$$
Then: $\nabla J=(2x-y+3, 2y-x-2)$.
The minimum must be at $\nabla J=0$.
Thus:
\begin{align}
2x+3 &= y\\
x+2 &= 2y
\end{align}
This implies $x+2=4x+6$, so $-3x = 4$. 
Thus, $x=-4/3$, and then $y = 2(-4/3)+3$. This is an extremal point.

The *type* of extremum is determined by the Hessian, which is
$$
\mathcal{H}[J] 
= \begin{bmatrix} \partial_{xx} J & \partial_{xy} J\\ \partial_{yx} J & \partial_{yy} J \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
The second derivative test works like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Second_derivative_test):
if $\mathcal{H}[J]$ is positive definite, we are at a minimum; negative definite, a maximum; otherwise, a saddle-point.
In 2D, this reduces to just looking at the determinant (eigenvalue product) and trace (eigenvalue sum) of the Hessian. Here:
$$
\det(\mathcal{H}[J])=4-1=3 \;\;\;\;\&\;\;\;\; \text{tr}(\mathcal{H}[J])=4
$$
The sum and product of the eigenvalues are both positive; hence, the matrix is positive definite at the extremal point and therefore a minimum.